Different result in Matlab and Python for StateSystem
While migrating to Python from Matlab, I get different result for StateSystem transform.
In Matlab,there is a 2 in 2 out system:
tf1 =
                      -4
  --------------------------------
  1e06 s^3 + 30000 s^2 + 300 s + 1 

Numerator: {[0 0 0 -4]}
Denominator: {[1000000 30000 300 1]}
tf2 =
0

Numerator: {[0 0 0]}
Denominator: {[5600 150 1]}
tf3 =
          0.75
  --------------------
  5600 s^2 + 150 s + 1

Numerator: {[0 0 0.7500]}
Denominator: {[5600 150 1]}
MatlabCode:
sys=[tf1,tf2;tf3,0];
sys_ss=ss(sys);

the output is:
sys_ss =
 
  A = 
              x1         x2         x3         x4         x5
   x1      -0.03    -0.0192  -0.008192          0          0
   x2    0.01562          0          0          0          0
   x3          0   0.007812          0          0          0
   x4          0          0          0   -0.02679   -0.01143
   x5          0          0          0    0.01562          0
 
  B = 
          u1     u2
   x1   0.25      0
   x2      0      0
   x3      0      0
   x4  0.125      0
   x5      0      0
 
  C = 
            x1       x2       x3       x4       x5
   y1        0        0  -0.1311        0        0
   y2        0        0        0        0  0.06857
 
  D = 
       u1  u2
   y1   0   0
   y2   0   0

In Python，I use control.ss:
import control

num11 = [0,0,0,-4]
num12 = [0,0,0]
num21 = [0,0,0.7500]
num22 = [0]

row1 = [num11, num12]
row2 = [num21, num22]
numerator = [row1,  row2]
denominator = [
                [[1000000, 30000, 300,1], [5600,150,1]],
                [[5600,150,1], [1]]
              ]
G = control.tf(numerator,
           denominator)
control.ss(G )

Then I got StateSpace:
enter image description here
What am I missing here? How can I fix to get the exact same result?
